# Using Ansible to implement certs rotation functionality in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: linux, kubernetes, coreos, kubernetes-security

How to use Ansible for certs rotation on different layers in kubernetes cluster?

Before we used fleet and now migrating to kubernetes.

Comment: _different layers in kubernetes cluster?_ what does "different layers" mean?

Comment: Is ansible new to your workflow, or you had it working under fleet and now would like to do the same steps under kubernetes?

Comment: Different layers: Infrastructure layer, Kubernetes layer, and Services layer (Upper platform services (elasticsearch, etc..) Lower platform services (etcd, pwx, etc...).

Comment: Yes, we implemented ansible to do certs rotation when using fleet and my concern is about how we can use that in kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

If I hear your situation correctly, then I think you will be happiest with a `DaemonSet` that installs (and optionally monitors) `ansible-pull.service` and `ansible-pull.timer` on the Nodes.

The `DaemonSet` ensures the container is scheduled on every Node (unlike a CronJob or such), and with `/etc/systemd/system` volume mounted into the container plus [go-systemd's ability to daemon-reload](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/v15/dbus/methods.go#L559) (along with the dbus socket, of course), the container can write out a suitably descriptive `.service` and `.timer` file for that Node.

Then `ansible-pull` will run as before, taking whatever steps your existing ansible playbooks did.

There are many approaches to how to achieve this similar action on non-Node machines, so I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

I don't know what you define as "Infrastructure" layer, but rotating the Kubernetes certs is relatively straightforward from ansible-pull's perspective: write out the new `worker.pem` and `worker.key` in `/etc/kubernetes/ssl`, bounce `kubelet.service` (or its `hyperkube` equivalent), voilà. Upper platform services I would expect are managed by the (ReplicaSet|Deployment|ReplicationController|etc) which owns them, meaning one can be a lot more declarative for in-cluster resources, having access to the full power of `ConfigMap`, `Secret`, `Service`, etc.